# HDMI Connection Does Not Send WM_DEVICE_ARRIVAL Message

Tags: c++, winapi, port, hdmi

I am attempting to detect when my TV is connected to my laptop via HDMI cable. I am using the WinAPI function `RegisterDeviceNotification()` to handle device messages.

When I connect my TV to my laptop (via HDMI cable) I never receive a WM_DEVICE_ARRIVAL message, only 3 WM_DEVICE_CHANGE events. **Is this normal?**

I really need the WM_DEVICE_ARRIVAL event because the lParam(or wParam, I forget) contains a structure that tells me the type of device connected and the device name whereas, afaik, the WM_DEVICE_CHANGE event does not contain this structure.

If its normal to not receive a WM_DEVICE_ARRIVAL message upon HDMI port insertion, **what other method could I use to determine the devices name and type when its connected?**

My only idea is: list all devices upon application startup, upon device connection react to the WM_DEVICE_CHANGE event and see if the list of devices has increased.

Comment: Is a new display monitor listed in Device Manager after connecting the HDMI link?

Answer (score 0):

You could poll `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CMONITORS)` or `EnumDisplayMonitors`.

The `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message is (usually) sent by applications and services which change system metrics, including the desktop resolution (which changes when HDMI is plugged if the desktop is extended, it wouldn't for mirroring).  You could use this to trigger the above polling, instead of relying solely on a timer.